# Can't use link to change the avatar of the bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When i use my bot i made it to change it's avatar with this code with putting the picture as an attachment but when i use link it gives me cannot read the property of url of unditified

```
client.on("message", async message =>{if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "profile")){ var image = message.attachments.first().url;
client.user.setAvatar(image);
message.reply("You have changed the Avatar")
```

}
});

Comment: Need some more details on this, that snippet of your code does not really tell much. What your code tells me now is that once message (any message) is sent it would try to "setAvatar" even if the message is plain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the message always has an attachment or don't try to set the avatar if there's none. You can ensure that by using something like this:

```js
if(!message.attachments.first() || message.attachments.first() == undefined) return
```

This will not execute any code after it, if no attachment is found.

If you have a link to the avatar you want to use and change it from the code directly, you could just put something like this in your `client.on("ready")` section:

```js
client.user.setAvatar('URLGoesHere')
```

Comment: thank you for that but if i want to change the avatar using a url not an attachment what should i type

Comment: I updated my answer, it now includes how to update it from the code directly ^^

Comment: thank you bro but i used image word to make it for the attachment so if i want the url what should i type i should type URLGoesHere or what?

Comment: Image word? No, if you have an URL to an image, you put it in the brackets behind `.setAvatar`. If you have an image on your local disk, you put the path to that image in the brackets. Aka something like `C:\Users\Me\Images\Avatar.png`. Also, it'd help me a bunch if you could upvote / accept my answer ^^